# Access state in one redux saga file from other redux saga file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga, redux-thunk

I am using react redux saga to implement something in a calendar application. This calendar application has multiple settings/params. One of them is the currentAccountId, which is in the initalState of a redux file and I want to render it dynamically.

```
const initialState = {
  currentAccountId: ''
};
```

However, in order to do this, I need access to the state object on a different redux saga file. How do I access this? Because when I try to do something along the lines of `const state = yield select();` outside of a generator function to access state, it tells me something like not accessible outside of a generator function. Is there some way I can access state?

Comment: You can use `useSelector` access state slice in your component. Or, use `store.getState()` to access the whole state anywhere.